# Query to get records for the past 30 days for different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose you have an sql server database with the following entries

```
CarMaker    CarModel    CarSalesPrice       CarSalesDate
---------------------------------------------------------
Maker A     A Model X V6    20000           12-23-2018
Maker B     B Model Z V6    30000           02-09-2019
Maker C     B Model Z V6    40000           04-08-2019
```

I'm trying to write a query to generate the total sales price per carMaker and model for the past 30 days and I'm stuck

```
SELECT
     CarModel, CarMaker, Count(totalSalesPrice)
FROM
     dbo.Cars

WHERE
    carSalesDate >= DATEADD(day,-30, getdate())
```

This code doesn't work and it's the only way I can think of accomplishing the task

Answer (score 1):

You need also aggregate by car model and maker using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
    CarModel,
    CarMaker,
    SUM(totalSalesPrice) AS totalSales
FROM dbo.Cars
WHERE
    carSalesDate >= DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
GROUP BY
    CarModel,
    CarMaker;
```

Comment: I think you would need sum(totalSalesPrice) instead of count

Answer (score 0):

You need an aggregation and `sum()`.  I would also recommend fixing the date comparison:

```
SELECT CarModel, CarMaker, SUM(totalSalesPrice)
FROM dbo.Cars
WHERE carSalesDate >= DATEADD(day,- 30, CONVERT(DATE, getdate()));
```

`GETDATE()` has a time component, which is misleading.  I'm not sure if you want -30 days, or -29 days.